# similarity percentage on images using regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I’m working on a project that uses classification and regression on a dataset containing 2 types of flowers: daisies and sunflowers. I have managed to apply random forest classification to find the class of each test image, but my question is how can I use regression to display the percentage of similarity that the image shares with each class?( ex a picture of a daisy is 87% daisy and 13% sunflower). I know regression isn’t the best approach but i’m doing this as an assignment so i must.

I have tried the random forest regressor and the scikit-learn `predict_proba` thing but my program just froze completely so I’m guessing I did something wrong.
this is a snippet of my code which is relevant to my problem:

```
# Convert lists to numpy arrays
test_images = np.array(test_images)
test_labels = np.array(test_labels)
test_probabilities = classifier.predict_proba(test_images)

# Create an interactive image viewer for the test set
class ImageViewer:
    def __init__(self, images, true_labels, predicted_probabilities):
        self.images = images
        self.true_labels = true_labels
        self.predicted_probabilities = predicted_probabilities
        self.index = 0

        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.display_image()

        self.next_button = Button(plt.axes([0.7, 0.02, 0.1, 0.05]), 'Next')
        self.next_button.on_clicked(self.next_image)

        plt.show()

    def display_image(self):
        img = self.images[self.index].reshape(256, 256, 3)
        true_class = self.true_labels[self.index]
        predicted_probs = self.predicted_probabilities[self.index]

        self.ax.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        self.ax.set_title(f"True: {true_class}\nPredicted Probabilities: {predicted_probs}")
        self.ax.axis('off')

    def next_image(self, event):
        self.index = (self.index + 1) % len(self.images)
        self.display_image()
        plt.draw()

# Initialize the image viewer for the test set
test_image_viewer = ImageViewer(test_images, test_labels, test_probabilities)
```

This code doesn't display anything, as I was saying I am also using classfication in the same program but it worked fine until I added regression. Also, is something wrong with the way I'm displaying images?

Comment: is `classifier` an instance of `RandomForestRegressor`? If so, it does not have a method `predict_proba`.

Comment: As said above, `RandomForestRegressor` naturally does not have a `predict_proba` method. But there is no RF to be found in your code - please post a [mre] (emphasis on *minimal*) with the *exact* problem shown.